# send a function to go html/template has an error: function " " not defined

Tags: function, go, go-templates

I can't send a function to template when I use another file instead of main.go

my problem is in Second Part.

First Part: (first part works fine.)

I can send a function->"humanSize" to the template->"temp.gohtml"

this is my directory:

```
app
|____main.go
|____templates
      |_____index
             |_____temp.gohtml
```

when I write a code like blow it works fine:

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var funcMap = template.FuncMap{
    "humanSize": humanSize,
}

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles("templates/index/temp.gohtml"))
}
func humanSize() string {
    return "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
}

func getPageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout,"temp.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", getPageHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil)
}
```

this is a code of templates/index/temp.gohmtl :

```
<html>
    <body>
        {{humanSize}}
    </body>
</html>
```

output is ok:

```
<html>
<body>

qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
</body>
</html>
```

Second Part: (I have a problem here.)

I want to move the code from main.go to controller/index.go

this is my new directory:

```
app
|____main.go
|____templates
|      |_____index
|             |_____temp.gohtml
|____controller
       |_____index.go
       |_____login.go     

//Answer: I edited this line just for another person wants to know what was the problem...I have imported some files in login.go same as index.go that cause "relative imports" and I got the error. in index.go also we have "relative imports" with config.go
```

I write a code in main.go :

```
import (
    Con "./controller"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Con.GetPageHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil)
}
```

and I write a code in controller/index.go :

```
package controller

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var funcMap = template.FuncMap{
    "humanSize": humanSize,
}

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles("templates/index/temp.gohtml"))
}
func humanSize() string {
    return "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
}

func GetPageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout,"temp.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
2019/04/12 21:44:49 template: temp.gohtml:11: function "humanSize" not defined
```

summary: when I write a code in main.go I can send a function to template but when I a code in controller/index.go I can't send a function to template.

Comment: I've copied your project and I don't see the error that you're seeing. The only difference in my test is that I didn't use relative import paths, which you also shouldn't use, noone should.

Comment: this is strange because I write the whole code here... any way this is my whole project https://www.mediafire.com/file/jdlk9c2tbzlzv8a/app.zip/file

Comment: *Do not use relative imports*. The actual problem seems to stem from your loading all the templates in you config package which is imported by the controller package in the login.go file, try commenting out the code in that file and your app will work.

Comment: I didn't understand very good why... but yes...you're right...when I commented app login.go files it works...can you send the answer for another go programmers? I'm junior fullstack programmer, do you think I should choose a framework or write without frame work? I read many topics about it and every body says don't use frameworks. maybe if I use frameworks , I will not have same problems...

Comment: Shivaprasad Bhat told me: You're using `Con ./controller` relative import .Use  `<github-path>/controller` format .. don't use `./controller`........BUT I can't understand the logic...I imported controller/index.go in main.go .... but in my controller/index.go I imported config.go and Model.go... If I put the controller in github path, how can I import config or model in my controller???

Comment: If you're using `$GOPATH` then the old rules apply, read this blog post for more info ([How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)). In short each import path should match the package's folder path **relative to `$GOPATH/src/`**. For example if the controller package is located in `$GOPATH/src/app/controller`, then the import path is `app/controller`. It is standard practice to have your projects live under a `github.com/username/` that's why your friend suggested `<github-path>` but it's not neccessary, what's neccessary is that your project lives under `$GOPATH/src/` and that...

Comment: ...you use the proper import path. The rules are a little bit different if you're using go modules and working outside of `$GOPATH`. If that's the case read this [article](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules). In that case the proper import path of a subfolder needs to include the module path.

Comment: Whether you use `$GOPATH` or `modules` you should not use relative import paths like `./controller` or `../../controller`, that's not only bad practice but I believe it doesn't work under every circumstance, so you should avoid it.